# Notfound.org с русской базой данных

Tags: сервисы

Не так давно в Европе был запущен сервис: [http://notfound.org](http://notfound.org/).

Вкратце суть такова: содержимое 404-ой страницы разрабатываемого Вами сайта отображается в виде "*страница не найдена, как и этот человек*". Далее фото и описание пропавшего реального человека, вытянутые из базы этого сервиса.

Насколько я могу судить- сервис работает только с европейской базой пропавших людей. Вопрос: есть ли аналоги в России или русская база пропавших? Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался, пробовал? Гуглится тяжело, так как попадаются только новости на запуск этого сервиса.

Comment: Я не думаю, что в России есть подобные проекты.

Comment: Я вообще не уверен, что у нас есть общедоступные базы пропавших людей.

Comment: Я тоже сомневаюсь.

Comment: Хм... А задумка прикольная... Жаль, что у нас спонсора на реализацию русской версии хрен найдешь.

Comment: В качестве базы пропавших можно использовать базу проекта "Жди меня". (http://poisk.vid.ru) Хотя я бы не назвал ее удобной.

Comment: Хоть что-то :). Но я, в таком случае, даже не знаю, с чего начать :)

Comment: @Cypher с серверного API естественно, как по мне, единственная проблема - как выбрать случайного человека, но она определенно решаемая

Comment: Можно поточнее, где начинать копать в сторону их API? Несколько раз садился просмотреть сайт на предмет "API", "Встроить", гуглил по сайту, но ничего не вижу. Или имется ввиду что-то другое?